# How do you do XmlIgnore in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Is there any way to prevent properties from being XML-serialized in .NET Core (which we would typically do using the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute before)?

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: I was hoping to use whatever comes with the framework.

Comment: So let's say `System.Xml.XmlSerializer`.

Comment: With such attributes missing, you should use DataContract and its related ones to explicitly define. `XmlIgnore` should be back in .NET Core 2.0 though.

Answer (score 2):

XmlIgnore is not in .net core (Or .net standard 1.6 which is probably more important).

This page [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md) on Github states that .net standard 2.0 will have XmlIgnore included (You can check further by viewing the raw diff between 1.6 and 2.0 [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/standard/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0_diff.md)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the System.Xml.Serialization package through NuGet.

Right-click Solution -> Manage Packages for Solution

Search for "System.Xml.Serialization" and add it to the projects that need it.

This has allowed me to use [XmlIgnore] attribute with .Net Standard 1.2

[image]